# Knockout manual subscription does not get triggered

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I've just started a project where I'm trying to use knockout for my viewmodel bindings. But I have a problem where I'm not able to get the view model to react to changes (through manual subscription) made in the view on the selectbox.

```
var viewModel = function() {
   var self = this;
   self.project = ko.observable();
   self.contractBorders = ko.observable();

   self.contractBorders.subscribe(function (newvalue) {
       alert('something changed!');
   });
};

viewModel.load = function() {
var data = {"project":{"name":"Project XYZ",
"number":338,"id":1,"isNew":false},"contractBorders":[{"name":"Border 1 grund","id":1},   
{"name":"Border 2","id":2},{"name":"Border 3","id":3}]}

viewModel.loadView(data);

};
viewModel.loadView = function(data) {
    self.project = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.project);
    self.contractBorders = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.contractBorders);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    
};

viewModel.load();
```

Im expecting the "self.contractBorders.subscribe" to be executed but it never happens. Im I doing it totally wrong?

I've created a Fiddle to reproduce the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vinblad/6zzSy/6/)

Any help would be appreciated!

/BR Vinblad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many little mistakes in binding and viewModel
1)

```
viewModel.loadView = function(data) {
    viewModel.project = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.project);
    viewModel.contractBorders = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.contractBorders);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    
};
```

2)

```
var viewModel = new function() {
```

3)

```
 <div class="span2">
                <select
```

4)

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" data-bind="value: project().name" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6zzSy/22/

Here I add observable value - `selectedBorder`
http://jsfiddle.net/6zzSy/24/

here I optimize your code
http://jsfiddle.net/6zzSy/25/

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. Spent 2 days on this problem!

Comment: Quick follow up question. Is it possible to get the object that the selectionbox changed to instead of just the Id of the item?

Comment: @Vinblad don't use `optionValue` parameter in `<select>`. http://jsfiddle.net/6zzSy/27/

Comment: @llya is it possible to set a the initial selected value in the selectbox. In reality the project item has a contractborder and I would like to set the selectbox initial value to the same as the project.contracBorder (that in my demo was not part of the jsondata) value?